# Foundation 5 build isn't complete

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation

I'm throwing my head against a wall here and would appreciate some help. So..

Lately, when I create a foundation project (or any existing project), I'm importing all of foundation with:

```
@import "settings";
@import "foundation";
```

However, when I compile the scss with compass, it will not import all of foundation. I end up with:

```
../bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation/components/_visibility.scss */
../bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation/components/_offcanvas.scss */
../bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation/components/_icon-bar.scss */
```

and the associated CSS in my final app.css, but no others are imported.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sass 3.4.0 introduced a backwards incompatible change to the `index()` function, which Foundation uses extensively to determine whether or not it should be generating styles.  This has been noted in the [Sass changelog](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_CHANGELOG.html#backwards_incompatibilities__must_read):

> index() now returns null rather than false if the value isn't found in the list.

Foundation has not been updated to be compatible with 3.4 yet, so you'll need to drop down to Sass 3.3.x until then.

See also:

- https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/5636
- https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1422