# Zurb Foundation styles missing when compass compile or compass watch is called

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation, compass

I have performed the following tasks on my system (Windows 7 64bit):

- Latest version of Node and npm installed
- Ruby 2.0 installed
- gem install compass
- gem install foundation
- npm install -g bower grunt-cli

I create a new foundation using this command

```
foundation new exampleProject
```

I perform this command while in the directory of exampleProject

```
compass watch
```

At this point, compass creates stylesheet directory with a file named app.css which contains **some** CSS which was apparently derived from foundation, but not all of it (it is missing the core features).

The code in my app.css file can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/vullnetyy/uLmmf8ge/

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25673067/foundation-5-build-isnt-complete

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.
Create your project with following line

```
foundation new mySite --libsass
```

And start your project compile with grunt

```
grunt build
```

Comment: I used cinnamon's link above: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25673067/foundation-5-build-isnt-complete