# Using Foundation SCSS with Yeoman angular-generator

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation, yeoman

I have installed Foundation via Bower, and I can use the default foundation.css fine by setting it as main in bower.json, and then it's included in the html automatically. So, now I want to theme my Foundation stuff, but I'm not sure how to do the scss stuff with compass and grunt and all that. How do I accomplish this?

It would be nice to be able to just have foundation work with compass and all that.

Help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
I added this to my bower.json in the foundation package:

```
"main": [
"scss/foundation.scss"
],
```

And then grunt adds the bower scss import and I manually added my settings files. I have the following in main.scss:

```
@import "foundation/settings";
// bower:scss
@import "foundation/scss/foundation.scss";
// endbower
```

I am importing the settings file and the foundation.scss file and I get no errors, but I don't see any of the styles on the screen at all. Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25673067/foundation-5-build-isnt-complete

Comment: So this is a bug with the latest Sass?

Comment: I looked at that bug, and I don't think that should be an issue anymore. The fix for it has been merged into foundation now. I'll try a fresh install, but I just reinstalled it yesterday.

Comment: There are 2 different problems referenced in that issue.  Only the first has been patched as far as I am aware.

Comment: Are you sure there are multiple problems there? It seemed to be the same problem and people were requesting both sass and foundation to fix it. Foundation merged the fix, so foundation should now work. Please take a look and confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was related to the bugs with the new version of Sass and Foundation. To fix I had to do:

`bower uninstall foundation`

Then manually go into bower.json in the root of my project and tell it I wanted Foundation 5.4.3 like so:
`"foundation": "zurb/bower-foundation#~5.4.3"`

Then just do a `bower cache clean` and a `bower install` and it should work again.