# Breaking changes Compass 0.12.5 => 1.0.1 with Foundation

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation, selector, compass

I have a class that extend .button and .tiny from Foundation 5 Framework.

index.scss

```
@import '_core/styles/compass';
@import '_core/styles/foundation';
@import '_core/styles/fonts';
@import '_core/styles/colors';
@import '../common/modules/components/components';
@import '_core/components/components';
@import '_core/styles/common';
@import '_core/styles/views';
```

_foundation.scss

```
@import '../../../common/lib/foundation/scss/foundation/components/global';
@import '../../../common/lib/foundation/scss/foundation/components/type';
@import '../../../common/lib/foundation/scss/foundation/components/block-grid';
@import '../../../common/lib/foundation/scss/foundation/components/buttons';
@import '../../../common/lib/foundation/scss/foundation/components/forms';
@import '../../../common/lib/foundation/scss/foundation/components/labels';
@import '../../../common/lib/foundation/scss/foundation/components/pagination';
@import '../../../common/lib/foundation/scss/foundation/components/tables';
@import '../../../common/lib/foundation/scss/foundation/components/grid';
@import '../../../common/lib/foundation/scss/foundation/components/top-bar';
@import '../../../common/lib/foundation/scss/foundation/components/alert-boxes';
@import '../../../common/lib/foundation/scss/foundation/components/visibility';
@import '../../../common/lib/foundation/scss/foundation/components/reveal'
```

_components.scss

```
.action{
    @extend .tiny;
    background-color: pink;
}
```

With compass 0.12.5 everything works perfectly fine. But if i upgrade my version to 1.0.1 compass telling me that the extend can't be applied because the .tiny selector does not exists.

I've read the changelog of compass and nothing seems to mention that there is a breaking change about extends or imports.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25673067/foundation-5-build-isnt-complete

Comment: You're right. Thanks for pointing me this thread.