# Getting Zurb Foundation SASS to Play Nice With Existing Application

Tags: sass, gruntjs, zurb-foundation, yeoman, bower

I've got an existing NodeJS express / AngularJS application that I need to make play nicely with Zurb foundation and in particular I am having problems with SASS.

The application was initially created with the yeoman angular generator.

I have installed zurb foundation via bower and the css side of things works fine. I can't however get the sass to compile properly. I seem to end up with missing parts of the css so there's virtually no styling present. The stylesheet is injected etc. and there's no errors as such when I build it.

My gruntfile looks like this (consolidated).

```
grunt.initConfig({

  pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
  yeoman: {
    client: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'client',
    dist: 'dist'
  },
  express: {
        ...
  },
  watch: {
    injectJS: {
      files: [
        '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.js',
        '!<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.spec.js',
        '!<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.mock.js',
        '!<%= yeoman.client %>/app/app.js'],
      tasks: ['injector:scripts']
    },
    injectCss: {
      files: [
        '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.css'],
      tasks: ['injector:css']
    },
    injectSass: {
      files: [
        '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.{scss,sass}'],
      tasks: ['injector:sass']
    },
    sass: {
      files: [
        '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.{scss,sass}'],
      tasks: ['sass', 'autoprefixer']
    },
    gruntfile: {
      files: ['Gruntfile.js']
    },
  },
  sass: {
    server: {
      options: {
        loadPath: [
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/bower_components/foundation/scss',
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/bower_components',
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/app',
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/components'
        ],
        compass: false
      },
      files: {
        '.tmp/app/app.css' : '<%= yeoman.client %>/app/app.scss'
      }
    }
  },
  injector: {
    scripts: {
            ...
    },
    sass: {
      options: {
        transform: function(filePath) {
          filePath = filePath.replace('/client/app/', '');
          filePath = filePath.replace('/client/components/', '');
          return '@import \'' + filePath + '\';';
        },
        starttag: '// injector',
        endtag: '// endinjector'
      },
      files: {
        '<%= yeoman.client %>/app/app.scss': [
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.{scss,sass}',
          '!<%= yeoman.client %>/app/app.{scss,sass}'
        ]
      }
    },

    // Inject component css into index.html
    css: {
      options: {
        transform: function(filePath) {
          filePath = filePath.replace('/client/', '');
          filePath = filePath.replace('/.tmp/', '');
          return '<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + filePath + '">';
        },
        starttag: '<!-- injector:css -->',
        endtag: '<!-- endinjector -->'
      },
      files: {
        '<%= yeoman.client %>/index.html': [
            '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.css'
        ]
      }
    }
  }
...
```

In my app.scss I just have this:

```
@import 'settings';
@import 'foundation';
```

And the _settings file is from the stock Zurb git repo and works without the rest  of my application.

When it compiles, I get some css starting with this:

```
/* Accessibility - hides the forward slash */
[aria-label="breadcrumbs"] [aria-hidden="true"]:after {
  content: "/"; }

.icon-bar.two-up .item {
  width: 50%; }
.icon-bar.two-up.vertical .item, .icon-bar.two-up.small-vertical .item {
  width: auto; }
@media only screen and (min-width: 40.063em) {
  .icon-bar.two-up.medium-vertical .item {
    width: auto; } }
@media only screen and (min-width: 64.063em) {
  .icon-bar.two-up.large-vertical .item {
    width: auto; } }
.icon-bar.three-up .item {
  width: 33.3333%; }
.icon-bar.three-up.vertical .item, .icon-bar.three-up.small-vertical .item {
  width: auto; }
@media only screen and (min-width: 40.063em) {
  .icon-bar.three-up.medium-vertical .item {
    width: auto; } }
@media only screen and (min-width: 64.063em) {
  .icon-bar.three-up.large-vertical .item {
    width: auto; } }
.icon-bar.four-up .item {
  width: 25%; }
.icon-bar.four-up.vertical .item, .icon-bar.four-up.small-vertical .item {
  width: auto; }
@media only screen and (min-width: 40.063em) {
  .icon-bar.four-up.medium-vertical .item {
    width: auto; } }
@media only screen and (min-width: 64.063em) {
  .icon-bar.four-up.large-vertical .item {
    width: auto; } }
.icon-bar.five-up .item {
  width: 20%; }
.icon-bar.five-up.vertical .item, .icon-bar.five-up.small-vertical .item {
  width: auto; }
```

I'm just learning sass and could do with some pointers. Could someone please help get this working

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25673067/foundation-5-build-isnt-complete

Comment: Completely different question

Comment: Have you uncommented out lines that you want used from the _settings.scss

Comment: @cport1 Yeah and I've tested in a vanilla installation with the same settings file. Works a treat.

Comment: Latest via bower, 5.4.6.

Comment: Just created a vanilla application with yeoman using sass. The stock scss files all compile nicely. It's only when I add foundation do the problems start