# Imported Foundation 5 components doesn't output as CSS

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation, codekit

I'm new to Foundation and SASS and working on a website project where I pulled the files prepared by another person with Foundation 5 included from Git.

I'm using Codekit 2 for the project and the changes I do in settings.scss and layout.scss (which has all the @import for the components) are compiled and outputted as CSS as intended. However, I can't see none of the imported components being used in the compiled CSS on the website and my grid is not displaying any associated classes with inspect element. Imports of other libraries such as Font awesome is working though.

I have tried uncommenting needed parts in settings.scss, changing around code etc.

Does it sound familiar to anyone? Could it be an error in the code or maybe a wrong setting in Codekit?

Comment: Are the components imported individually or are you using `@import "foundation"`?

Comment: They are imported individually.

Comment: I've not used Codekit before but it may be worth compiling via command line using Compass to check if it's not just an issue with Codekit. Also, setting the output to expanded development will give you a clearer picture of where things are going wrong in the output CSS.

Comment: Do you get a message from Codekit ... a popup (Mac OS) that says 'Succes' or 'Failed' after saving file (compiling) ... !? If saving fails you have to look at the log files of Codekit ... maybe there you can find the key to what's the problem.

Comment: I have now switched to compiling with Grunt via command line but the issue of

Comment: I got no errors in Codekit when compiling. Now I have switched to compiling with Grunt but I still have the same issuse.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Foundation 5 build isn't complete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25673067/foundation-5-build-isnt-complete)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it works now, I found a solution here: http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/19040-no-foundation-styling-imported-to-appcss-sass-f5

It was a bug on line 12 in _functions.scss - I guess my version of Foundation is from before they fixed that. I replaced:

`@if (index($modules, $name) == false) {`

with

`@if(not index($modules, $name)) {`

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution (so many people do't) - this helped me fix an old (but live!) project. Phew.